# How to execute a gradle task before any distributions are built

Tags: gradle

I've got a gradle build with source and javadoc jars and I'd like these tasks to be executed before distZip and distTar, is there a dependency that captures both of those for use with shouldRunAfter.

Right now I've got:

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'javadoc'
    from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

tasks.distZip.shouldRunAfter tasks.javadocJar
tasks.distTar.shouldRunAfter tasks.javadocJar
tasks.distZip.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar
tasks.distTar.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar
```

I'd like to condense down those four shouldRunAfter to two which captures both distZip and distTar.

Comment: I get the sense that using task dependencies might be more inline with Gradle best practices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use groovy syntax to make this shorter

```
[distZip, distTar]*.shouldRunAfter javadocJar, sourcesJar
```

Probably you also want `dependsOn` instead of `shouldRunAfter` so that the jars are built whenever one of the dist tasks is enabled.